# Drupal 6- 404 is not showing for menu item URL pattern implemented using hook_menu

Tags: drupal-6, http-status-code-404, hook-menu

I have a hook menu

```
$items['mypage'] = array(
    'title' => t('My Page title'),
    'description' => '',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback'=> 'my_home_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
);
```

Now when I access a page which is not existing like "mypage/blahblah"  it will show my home page(ie http://www.mydomain.com/mypage/blahblah is rendering content of http://www.mydomain.com/mypage). Instead of this I need to show a 404 page.

Can anybody give comment on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to paste the following code in your page call back function "my_home_page"

```
if ('' != arg(1)){
    drupal_not_found();
}
```

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: It's Worked for me
Thanks rpk :)